# jQuery: how to get val() of children('input').eq?

Tags: jquery

There's three input fields inside '.edit'. How to get the value of each one of them using jQuery?

```
$submit.click(value);      

function value () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var $input = $('.edit').children('input').eq(i).val();
        console.log($input);
    }
}

<div class="edit">
    <h3>Headline</h3>
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="text" id="one">
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="text" id="two">
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="text" id="three">
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Doesn't work. Why? And also is it possible to set a default value: `.val() || 'unknown'`?

Comment: show your html mark up

Comment: Only if you could provide us the HTML and full code, may be we can look into it.

Comment: Where's your `.edit` element?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Updated.

Comment: @ArtemZ What's the definition of `$submit`?

Comment: var $submit = $('.submit')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through the inputs under `.edit` on submit click and obtain each input value using `$(this)`

```js
$('.submit').click(function(){

  $('.edit').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){

  console.log($(this).val());

});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit">
    <h3>Headline</h3>
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="text" id="one" value="default">
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="text" id="two">
    <span>Text</span>
    <input type="text" id="three">
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to set a default value? Somenthing like || 'default' in vanilla?

Comment: you can use the html `value` attribute , check the edit... Or with jquery val as `$("#element").val('default');` called on page load.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.submit').click(function() {
  $('.edit').find('input').each(function(index, value) {

    console.log("index is " + index + " " + "value is " + $(this).val())


  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit">
  <h3>Headline</h3>
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="text" id="one" value='1'>
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="text" id="two" value='2'>
  <span>Text</span>
  <input type="text" id="three" value='3'>
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.